# Scheduled SQL LOAD DATA INFILE script execution in Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm trying to schedule a LOAD DATA INFILE script to periodically update a MySql database table from a CSV file.

The scheduled method is executed, but not the script itself.
Script executes fine manually.

The script is located in /resources/sql/

DbConfig.java

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-database");
    ds.setUsername("username");
    ds.setPassword("password");

    // Update DB on startup
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator(), ds);

    return ds;
}

@Bean
public ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.setSqlScriptEncoding("UTF-8");
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/sql/ProductUpdate.sql"));
    return populator;
}

// The scheduled method
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 15000) // Every 15 sec
public void updateProductsTable() {
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator(), this.dataSource());
}
```

SQL script

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE products_temp
(
  product_code varchar(100),
  supplier_number int(10),
  price double,
  product_name varchar(255),
  stock_amount double,
  buying_price double
);


LOAD DATA CONCURRENT LOCAL INFILE 'C:\path\to\csv\product-data.txt' REPLACE 
INTO TABLE products_temp
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(product_code, supplier_number, @price, product_name, @stock_amount, 
@buying_price)
SET
  price = replace(@price, ',', '.'),
  stock_amount = replace(@stock_amount, ',', '.'),
  buying_price = replace(@buying_price, ',', '.');

INSERT INTO products (product_code, supplier_number, price, product_name, 
stock_amount, buying_price)
SELECT product_code, supplier_number, price, product_name, stock_amount, 
buying_price FROM products_temp
WHERE product_code NOT IN (SELECT product_code FROM products);

UPDATE products a
JOIN products_temp b ON a.product_code = b.product_code AND 
a.supplier_number = b.supplier_number
SET a.price = b.price,
    a.product_name = b.product_name,
    a.stock_amount = b.stock_amount,
    a.buying_price = b.buying_price;

DROP TABLE products_temp;
```

I expect the sql script executed every 15 seconds, but actually the script doesn't execute at all.

This code produces no errors.

Comment: "I expect the sql script executed every 15 seconds, but actually the script doesn't execute at all." Do you get errors?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, no errors. Editing now.

Comment: *@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * ? * *") // Every 15 sec* why you expect every 15 sec? From the javadoc: *E.g. "0 * * * * MON-FRI" means once per minute on weekdays (at the top of the minute - the 0th second).*

Comment: "This code produces no errors." it seams you don't fetch errors or catch them in `try () catch (Exception exception) {}` code blocks or the `ResourceDatabasePopulator` class never throws Exceptions?

Comment: The script can fail with a few reasons..1) trying to read a directory where the program user does not have read rights. 2) reading files that use the ucs2, utf16, utf16le, or utf32 character sets 3) `DROP TABLE products_temp;` which should be `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE products_temp;`

Comment: @RaymondNijland ResourceDatabasePopulator never throws Exceptions.

Comment: "ResourceDatabasePopulator never throws Exceptions."  Try running the SQL code directly in MySQL to see if it errors  or not if it does error one more reason to avoid using Spring framework because off not showing errors/exceptions on critical code paths which is terrible.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The script executes fine manually inside the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to fix it by separating each SQL query into a separate script.

Solution:

```
private ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScripts(new ClassPathResource("/sql/products/Create.sql"),
            new ClassPathResource("/sql/products/Load.sql"),
            new ClassPathResource("/sql/products/Insert.sql"),
            new ClassPathResource("/sql/products/Update.sql"),
            new ClassPathResource("/sql/products/Drop.sql"));

    return populator;
}

// The scheduled method
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 15000) // Every 15 sec
public void updateProductsTable() {
    databasePopulator().execute(dataSource());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **cron job expression** is wrong, try executing with the following Scheduling Method, I have updated the the **CRON**

```
 @Bean
 @Scheduled(cron = "0/15 * * * * ?") // Every 15 sec
 public void updateProductsTable() {
 DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator(), this.dataSource());
 }
```

Comment: You are correct. However, the script still does not run. I have edited my code to use fixedDelay instead to get the focus off the CRON expression :)

Comment: Is Scheduling Enabled in your application? If not, add this anotation "@EnableScheduling" in your main app runner class.